How to distinguish between USB, Smartphone, Tablet and PDF reader when they are connected to PC
I want to detect and be able to differentiate the type of devices that are connected to Windows.
Is there any difference in the logs generated by Windows Event Monitor when an external devices is connected through USB ?
For example, I want to know what is the difference between logs when a pen-drive is connected and when a smartphone is connected.
I want this for a security application which should be able to report what type of device have been connected.

Smartphones will usually provide either MTP or PTP device class (plus adb only if debugging is turned on).  Pen drive will be mass storage.  You can tell the difference between these (although I don't know how to do it with existing logs from Windows Event Monitor, I only know with Device Manager queries while my software is running).  Telling the difference between a smartphone and a camera, which both use PTP... would probably need a database of VID/PID information.

Yeah, you can use SetupAPI to traverse the device tree that Windows generates; this is similar to looking in your Device Manager in "View by Connection" mode.  You can get the vendor ID and product ID of each USB device, and look at what drivers Windows has associated with them and their child devices.

@DavidGrayson thanks David, Can you explain a bit more on how can I look at what drivers Windows has associated ?

I forget the details, but libusbp does it and here is the specific part of the code that does it:  https://github.com/pololu/libusbp/blob/1d739425a2d2bc968822b37dcaae54efce6fa7b1/src/windows/generic_interface_windows.c#L50
